how to perfrom a syntactic analysis of the sentence in news from CNN？
"It has been like 5,000 little detective stories — trying to find out which author or article Darwin noted having — it is a joy to strike gold and find the exact source he was referring to," van Wyhe said.
“which author or article Darwin noted having”
If this sentence is a clause, ”noted” must be a predicate. So what is the role of “having” in this clause?

You don't say what they are talking about, but I see that Dr van Wyhe is an expert on Charles Darwin. Even the most intelligent people don't always talk in complete grammatical sentences. Perhaps he meant to say "Darwin noted having seen' or 'read' but for some reason left out a word and went on to his next thought.

I attach the address to here ：link

This link should have been provided in the question.  With its help I can supply an answer.

I see from the link you provided that an earlier paragraph says "Darwin used abbreviated or vague ways to refer to journals and pamphlets in his collection", so Dr van Wyhe probably means "which author or article Darwin made a note that he had in his collection".

thxxxxxxx a lot!
